# Verify that method of the System Under Test was called

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have the `DatabaseFacade` class with these three methods:

```
public class DatabaseFacadeImpl implements DatabaseFacade {


    private final SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DatabaseFacadeImpl(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        this.database = database;
    }

    @Override
    public long insertOrUpdate(String tableName, ContentValues values, String columnId) throws SQLException {
        try {
            return insertOrThrow(tableName, values);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return updateOrThrow(tableName, values, columnId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long insertOrThrow(String tableName, ContentValues values) {
        return database.insertOrThrow(tableName, null, values);
    }

    @Override
    public int updateOrThrow(String tableName, ContentValues values, String columnId) throws SQLException {
        final String whereClause = columnId + "=?";
        final String[] whereArgs = {values.getAsString(columnId)};

        return database.update(tableName, values, whereClause, whereArgs);
    }
}
```

I want to test in the `insertOrUpdate` that in case the insert fails, the update method is called. Right now I do it like so with Mockito:

```
@Test
public void insertOrUpdate_withUnSuccessfullInsert_updates() {
    DatabaseFacadeImpl databaseFacade = spy(new DatabaseFacadeImpl(mock(SQLiteDatabase.class)));
    when(databaseFacade.insertOrThrow(tableName, contentValues)).thenThrow(SQLiteException.class);
    final String columnId = "1";
    // databaseFacade.insertOrThrow counts as an invocation
    reset(databaseFacade); 
​
​    // databaseFacade.insertOrUpdate counts as an invocation as well
    databaseFacade.insertOrUpdate(tableName, contentValues, columnId);

    verify(databaseFacade).insertOrUpdate(tableName, contentValues, columnId);
    verify(databaseFacade).insertOrThrow(tableName, contentValues);
    verify(databaseFacade).updateOrThrow(tableName, contentValues, columnId);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(databaseFacade);
}
```

The problem with this is that both the `insertOrThrow` and the `insertOrUpdate` are counted as invocations therefore I have to reset them or verify them.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason (e.g. design for subclasses) that you have to verify the method is called? Ideally, you would treat the internal call as an implementation detail, and instead only check the behavior according to the class or method's general contract (return values or interactions with external services).

Comment: @JeffBowman The reason why I chose to validate that the method itself is called instead of the result of the method is because `insertOrThrow` is already tested in a different test. So I did not want to duplicate test logic in different places because changing the implementation of `insertOrThrow` would mean changing test logic in multiple places.

Comment: You shouldn't have to change your test when the implementation changes, only when the interface does. I think duplicating test logic is much better than testing implementation details, but that's an opinion, not a universal truth. You'll find it easier to test my way, though, especially when you don't have to worry about partial mocks (which is your alternative).